# Matlab to Python numpy indexing and multiplication issue

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following line of code in MATLAB  which I am trying to convert to Python `numpy`:

```
pred = traindata(:,2:257)*beta;
```

In Python, I have:

```
pred = traindata[ : , 1:257]*beta
```

`beta` is a 256 x 1 array.

In MATLAB,

```
size(pred) = 1389 x 1
```

But in Python,

```
pred.shape = (1389L, 256L)
```

So, I found out that multiplying by the `beta` array is producing the difference between the two arrays.

How do I write the original Python line, so that the size of `pred` is 1389 x 1, like it is in MATLAB when I multiply by my beta array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that `beta` is in fact a 1D `numpy` array.  In `numpy`, 1D arrays are not row or column vectors where MATLAB clearly makes this distinction.  These are simply 1D arrays agnostic of any shape.  If you must, you need to manually introduce a new singleton dimension to the `beta` vector to facilitate the multiplication.  On top of this, the `*` operator actually performs **element-wise** multiplication.  To perform matrix-vector or matrix-matrix multiplication, you must use `numpy`'s [`dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) function to do so.

Therefore, you must do something like this:

```
import numpy as np # Just in case

pred = np.dot(traindata[:, 1:257], beta[:,None])
```

`beta[:,None]` will create a 2D `numpy` array where the elements from the 1D array are populated along the rows, effectively making a column vector (i.e. 256 x 1).  However, if you have already done this on `beta`, then you don't need to introduce the new singleton dimension.  Just use `dot` normally:

```
pred = np.dot(traindata[:, 1:257], beta)
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem.  My array is now 1389 x 1 in Python by using the first line of code that you provided.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick No problem!  Glad I could help.  Good luck!

Comment: If I have a different array that I need to add another singleton dimension to, how do I do that?  My `traindata` array is just '(1389L,)'.  How do I make it '(1389L, 1L)'?

Comment: @Nick It's simply `traindata = traindata[:,None]`.  The `None` in the second argument allows you to create an array of two dimensions instead of one where you've explicitly created the second dimension by yourself.  It would then populate the 2D matrix with the elements row-wise.  In general, this works for any `numpy` array where if you had `N` dimensions, you would create a `N+1` dimension array with the last dimension having a size of 1.  The `(1389L,)` denotes that `traindata` is a 1D array.  If you want to perform matrix multiplication, the singleton dimension inclusion is required.

Comment: @Nick If you simply want to find the dot product of two `numpy` arrays, none of this singleton stuff I was talking about is required.  Just do `np.dot(traindata, beta)` assuming they're both 1D arrays of the same size.  Just use `dot` by itself.  For 1D arrays, this performs the dot product between two arrays but it performs matrix-vector multiplication or matrix-matrix multiplication between two matrices/vectors.  Matrix-vector or matrix-matrix multiplication boils down to a sequence of dot product calculations anyway, which is why `dot` has its name.

Comment: Thanks for the help rayryeng.  I have one more issue where I am translating Matlab to Python.  Is the Matlab equivalent of: `predlabels(predindex2) = 2;` equal to the Python: 'predlabels[predindex2] = 2' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122228/discussion-between-nick-and-rayryeng).

Comment: Also note that for python 3.5 or higher, you can replace `np.dot(a, b)` with `a @ b`.  The `@` operator does matrix multiplication like the MATLAB `*` operator (while the `*` operator behaves like the MATLAB `.*` operator).

Comment: @TheBlackCat good to know! I'm still on 2.7. Didn't know about this. Makes it much easier.

Comment: @rayryeng: Unless there is a specific package you need that depends on Python 2.7, you really should be using Python 3.5 for any sort of numerical computing.  It has a bunch of advantages in that area.

Comment: @TheBlackCat It's mostly laziness at this point.  That and for the moment, I haven't had the need to use Python but I most likely will later.  Thanks for the tip!